# IPv6 in an Ubuntu 16.04 Behind a Router

Tags: 16.04, ipv6, dhcpv6

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 behind a router.  I can get IPv6 on the router working, but it fails on the client.  If anyone has any input on how I can resolve that, I'd appreciate it.

I can use either SLAAC (radvdump output, below) or DHCPv6 to get an IP from the ISP, resulting in an IP based on the MAC of the router's WAN interface, plus a link-local.  **`ip -6 addr` on the router** shows:

```
inet6 2607:X:X:X:Y:yff:fey:Y/64 scope global dynamic
```

Then, I can set the router's LAN interface to static: `2607:X:X:X::/64` and use the routers's stateless or stateful DHCP server to get **addresses for the client** (first address only present when using the *stateful* server):

```
inet6 2607:X:X:X::x/128         scope global dynamic
inet6 2607:X:X:X:Y':Y':Y':Y'/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
inet6 2607:X:X:X:Z:Z:Z:Z/64     scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute dynamic
```

**`ip -6 route` on the client** (first route only present when using the *stateful* server and fe80::Y:yff:fey:Y is the link-local ip of the router's LAN interface)

```
2607:X:X:X::x dev enp0s25 proto kernel metric 256 expires 86292sec pref medium 
2607:X:X:X::/64 via fe80::Y:yff:fey:Y dev enp0s25 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
2607:X:X:X::/64 dev enp0s25 proto kernel metric 256 expires 7090sec pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp0s25 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::Y:yff:fey:Y dev enp0s25 proto static metric 100 pref medium
```

When the router is set to use DHCP with the ISP, I can also try to dispense with the static setting for the router's LAN interface, by using prefix delegation; but then whether I use stateful or stateless DHCP with the client, I only get a link-local address. This seems odd as the prefix/netmask are included in the ISP's router advertisement (below).

**---------------------------------------------**

**# radvdump** [run on the router]

```
interface ath0
{
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    # Note: {Min,Max}RtrAdvInterval cannot be obtained with radvdump
    AdvManagedFlag off;
    AdvOtherConfigFlag on;
    AdvReachableTime 0;
    AdvRetransTimer 0;
    AdvCurHopLimit 64;
    AdvDefaultLifetime 1800;
    AdvHomeAgentFlag off;
    AdvDefaultPreference medium;
    AdvSourceLLAddress on;

    RDNSS 2607:X:X:X::53
    {
        AdvRDNSSPreference 0;
        AdvRDNSSOpen off;
        AdvRDNSSLifetime 1800;
    }; # End of RDNSS definition


    prefix 2607:X:Y:Y::/64
    {
        AdvValidLifetime 2592000;
        AdvPreferredLifetime 604800;
        AdvOnLink on;
        AdvAutonomous on;
        AdvRouterAddr off;
    }; # End of prefix definition

}; # End of interface definition
#
# radvd configuration generated by radvdump 1.2
# based on Router Advertisement from fe80::Z:Z:Z:Z
# received by interface ath0
```

**/etc/network/interfaces** is unchanged from the ubuntu install:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I also note here the **output of `sysctl`**.  [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/652906) indicates I may need to change some of these, but others indicate that changes should be in the interfaces file and/or Network Manager, and that these don't play well with sysctl. It's the enp0s25 interface that connects to the LAN:

```
$ sudo sysctl -a | grep accept_ra

net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_defrtr = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_from_local = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_min_hop_limit = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_mtu = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_pinfo = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_defrtr = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_from_local = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_min_hop_limit = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_mtu = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_pinfo = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 1
net.ipv6.conf.enp0s25.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.enp0s25.accept_ra_defrtr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.enp0s25.accept_ra_from_local = 0
net.ipv6.conf.enp0s25.accept_ra_min_hop_limit = 1
net.ipv6.conf.enp0s25.accept_ra_mtu = 1
net.ipv6.conf.enp0s25.accept_ra_pinfo = 0
net.ipv6.conf.enp0s25.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.enp0s25.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_defrtr = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_from_local = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_min_hop_limit = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_mtu = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_pinfo = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 1
net.ipv6.conf.virbr0.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.virbr0.accept_ra_defrtr = 1
net.ipv6.conf.virbr0.accept_ra_from_local = 0
net.ipv6.conf.virbr0.accept_ra_min_hop_limit = 1
net.ipv6.conf.virbr0.accept_ra_mtu = 1
net.ipv6.conf.virbr0.accept_ra_pinfo = 1
net.ipv6.conf.virbr0.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.virbr0.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 1
net.ipv6.conf.virbr0-nic.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.virbr0-nic.accept_ra_defrtr = 1
net.ipv6.conf.virbr0-nic.accept_ra_from_local = 0
net.ipv6.conf.virbr0-nic.accept_ra_min_hop_limit = 1
net.ipv6.conf.virbr0-nic.accept_ra_mtu = 1
net.ipv6.conf.virbr0-nic.accept_ra_pinfo = 1
net.ipv6.conf.virbr0-nic.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.virbr0-nic.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 1
net.ipv6.conf.wlp3s0.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.wlp3s0.accept_ra_defrtr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.wlp3s0.accept_ra_from_local = 0
net.ipv6.conf.wlp3s0.accept_ra_min_hop_limit = 1
net.ipv6.conf.wlp3s0.accept_ra_mtu = 1
net.ipv6.conf.wlp3s0.accept_ra_pinfo = 0
net.ipv6.conf.wlp3s0.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.wlp3s0.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 0
```

Comment: Looks like you configured the same prefix on WAN and LAN sides of the router. That's incorrect. Your ISP need to route a prefix to your WAN address such that you can use that on the LAN. How to get a routed prefix depends on the ISP. Some require your router to request a prefix through DHCPv6. I have come across one that have a website where you can get a routed prefix.

Comment: Thanks @kasperd.  It does appear there is no PD with DHCP, as far as I can make out - though I'd like to be 100% sure.  I'll either have to go for a bridge - in which case I need to figure out how to assign myself non-mac based IPv6's - or run an IPv6 NAT, which I'll also have to figure out how to do.  The project exhausted me though, so I'm going to get back to it in a bit....

Comment: Both of those approaches are absolutely inferior. A routed prefix is the way to go. If your router requests a delegated prefix and you don't get a routed prefix that way, you need to ask your ISP how to get a routed prefix.

Comment: While I agree, this is an unsupported university visitor network.  So I'm on my own.  I'll try to find out how to do a packet capture & make sure there's no prefix advertised, but otherwise those are the choices.